# What does it stand for in bit operations?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

What do those lines of code stand for?

```
payloadType = header[1] & 127;
sequenceNumber = unsigned_int(header[3]) + 256*unsigned_int(header[2]);
timeStamp = unsigned_int(header[7])
               + unsigned_int(header[6])
               + 65536*unsigned_int(header[5])
               + 16777216*unsigned_int(header[4]);
```

Where header is a byte[12] and the method unisigned_int is this:

```
private int unsigned_int(byte b) {
    if(b >= 0) {
        return b;
    }
    else {
        return 256 + b;
    }
}
```

Thank you for answering!

Comment: What's the question? The code manipulates the bits in a reasonably obvious fashion. What are you asking?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for answering and for editing my post. I'm pretty new on stackoverflow and i'm getting into its vibe slowly. I apologize for my english as well.

Comment: Paul, my question was exactly about what this obvious fashion (for me not, I'm new) does: unsigned_int(header[3]) + 256*unsigned_int(header[2])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 payloadType = header[1] & 127;
```

Strip the sign bit off header 1 / get bottom 7 bits

```
sequenceNumber = unsigned_int(header[3]) + 256*unsigned_int(header[2]);
```

extract a 16 bit value from the header

```
 timeStamp = unsigned_int(header[7])
           + unsigned_int(header[6])
           + 65536*unsigned_int(header[5])
           + 16777216*unsigned_int(header[4]);
```

extract a 32 bit value from the header. With the bug as observed by Mark Byers.

```
private int unsigned_int(byte b) {
     if(b >= 0) {
         return b;
     }
     else {
         return 256 + b;
     }
}
```

convert an integer from -128 to 127 (i.e. a byte) into a 8 bit unsigned int represented as an integer. Equivalent to

```
 return b & 255
```

Answer (score 1):

It's converting bytes to integers.

I think there is a bug here:

```
+ 256 * unsigned_int(header[6])
  ^^^^^
```

Also instead of writing `x * 256`, `x * 65536`, `x * 16777216` it would be more clear to write `x << 8`, `x << 16`, `x << 24`.